# How was this website made, what's Frontpage 5.0?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser, frontpage

A friend of mine had "**a friend make a website**" for her, but this person is no longer contactable, so she asked me "why it looks **different in Firefox** and the links don't work".

Looking at the source, it seems to have been made with "**Frontpage 5.0**" but also has a **"Microsoft Office" XML namespace**.

What I find interesting is that it apparently checks the browser and if it is not IE, it simply outputs a website made up of **large, bad looking .gifs** on which, not surprisingly, the links don't work.

Here is the site: http://sprachschule-polyglott.de

I'm theoretically interested in how this site was made, and thought it might be interesting for others, perhaps as an example for a presentation of the bad old days of the Internet, a relic from last decade's browser wars.

Can anyone tell me **how this site was made**?

- Was this made with **Frontpage 98**?
- Or is it just an export-to-website output from some version of **Microsoft Word**?
- I actually used Frontpage 98 back in the 90s but I don't recall even then that it output "an alternative website as .gifs" for Netscape. That's pretty non-compatible even for the day. Anyone know how the background to this method of "browser compatibility", was it an option in Frontpage or Microsoft word to "**render as graphics for non-IE browsers**"?

Comment: +1 Damn you for making me remember FrontPage 98 :)

Comment: yes, it was very practical piece of software made for an IE-only world that never came to be

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The website (thank you for finding it - it's a gem) was created using Microsoft Publisher 2003 with the Frontpage 2002 Server Extensions.

Even though Wikipedia says there was no Frontpage version 5, it is not totally correct. [This Frontpage](http://www.seoconsultants.com/frontpage/history/) Fanboy (who would have thought someone like this existed?) labels Frontpage 2002 as Version 5. Frontpage 2002 was delivered with Office XP and according to the [official Microsoft page for the version of Office XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291331) Frontpage 2002's release version was `10.2623.2625` - Wikipedia actually has this right... weird.

Searching Google you will find many references to "FrontPage 5.0" or the "FrontPage 5.0 Web Object Library" - the mystery continues, so what the heck is Frontpage 5.0?

Frontpage Server Extensions to the rescue! The [Frontpage 2002 Server Extensions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/891314) have the version number `5.0.2.6738`. First mystery solved.

So why does the website render as GIF in Firefox and as a regular website in Internet Explorer? Microsoft Publisher to the rescue! (Lot's of rescuing being done here...) MS Publisher had the ability to publish a website as VML, GIFs as well as HTML. In case of our website-friend here it was Microsoft Publisher 2003 outputting "filtered HTML" - how do I know? The "filelist.xml" and all the VML code gives it away. This [Microsoft Publisher blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/dbartosik/archive/2006/01/05/80960.aspx) actually has a list of Publisher created website as well as an explanation on how to find out which version of Publisher was used:

> If produced in Publisher's "Filtered" html (lightest page), and you see lots of VML/XML code and "filelist.xml" in the first few lines of the source it's 2003.

---

**To sum this up:**
The website was created using Microsoft Publisher 2003, outputting a "filtered" HTML. The server the website is running on, is using Frontpage 2002 Server Extensions.

---

PS: I could be wrong about the last part (server running server extensions) - maybe Microsoft Publisher used the Frontpage 2002 Server Extensions to render the HTML and hence the Generator is "FrontPage 5.0"

Comment: +1 for a heck of a lot of research in ancient technologies here ;)

Answer (score 2):

My bet is that it was made with Microsoft Publisher, which had an option to output the whole site as graphics. There was no standalone version of Front Page 5 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_FrontPage).

The VML used in the source code would give some clues to its age; the VML standard was proposed in 1998.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language

Another clue is the use of DHTML behaviors, which were introduced in IE 5.5 in 2000.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531079(VS.85).aspx